# Von Neumann algebra generated by a set

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a unital $C^*$ algebra,$\pi:A\to B(H)$ is a representation of $A$.Then the von Neumann algebra generated by $\pi(A)$ is equal to $\pi(A)^{"}$.

Is the weak$*$ closure of $\pi(A)$ equal to $\pi(A)^{"}$?When $A$ is non-unital,Is the von Neumann algebra generated by $\pi(A)$ also equal to $\pi(A)^{"}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unless your representation is degenerate, meaning that $\pi(A)H$ is not dense. For an easy example of what the problem is consider $A=c_0$ and $\pi:A\to B(\ell^2(\mathbb N)\oplus \ell^2(\mathbb N))$ be given by $\pi(a)(x,y)=(ax,0)$. This is degenerate because $\pi(A)H\subset \ell^2(\mathbb N)\oplus 0$. Now you have 
$$
\pi(A)''=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\oplus B(\ell^2(\mathbb N)),
$$
because anything of the form $(0,y)$ commutes with everything coming from $\pi$. The von Neumann algebra generated by $\pi(A)=c_0 \oplus 0$ is arguably $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\oplus 0$, which does not have the same identity as $B(H)$.

Comment: But in the example, $A$ is unital.For the 1st question,by double commutant theorem,the sot closure of $\pi(A)$ is equal to $\pi(A)^{"}$.If we consider the weak* closure,is it also true?

Comment: Ok, so now I made the example unnecessarily more complicated to have $A$ non-unital. And, what do you mean exactly by "weak$^*$-topology" here?

Comment: But in murphy's book,there is a statement,If the set $C\subset B(H)$ is self-adjoint and containing $id_H$,then the vna generated by C is equal to $C^{"}$.If $C$ is non-unital, is it also true?

Comment: There is a * homomorphism f from $\pi(A)$ to $\pi(A)^{"}$,Is the weak* closure of $f(\pi(A))$ equal to $\pi(A)^{"}$?

Comment: It is true if $C$ is non-degenerate. It's not unital that is crucial for the double commutant theorem it's "non-degenerate".